# NSThread to slow down Array being printed to console in Objective-C? so confused

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsthread, nslog

So I have an array with objects `@"One", "Two", "Three", "Mouse"` and I want to have each word of the array NSLog'ed to the console in half second increments. I also would like to be able to switch to 1 second increments instead. Can anyone please help me write this code?

I was tipped that I can use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];` but I dont know how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apples:",@"bacon",@"corn",@"donuts",@"elfs",@"fidge",nil];

// the number of seconds to wait between printing each item
double secondsToSleep = 1.0;

for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:secondsToSleep];
    NSLog(@"item at index %i is %@",i,[food objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

if thats not the best way, let me know :)